# Anova vs Summary in the analysis of models and variables

Tags: regression, anova, descriptive-statistics

I'm just approaching to the regression model analysis in R software. I would like to ask some particulars about the difference between the `anova` test used to compare models and the simple `summary` command.
I explain you what I mean.

I have a datasets and I have to estimate a linear regression between a response and one or probably many predictors. In order to analyse the significance of each variable I usually start from the `summary`, after having build my model with `lm` and the output tells me which predictor is significant through the p-value and the significance stars.

Proceeding in this way, when I should use the anova test? Since I can already check the significance through the summary, why should I build another model with different variables and then perform anova?

What I am really asking is: **when** I should use `summary` and when `anova` and what are the **conclusion** I can obtain from them in the prospective of my analysis? Remember that my final goal is to build the best model for the description of the regression.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that this site is not intended as a resource for software specific or programming questions. For instance, I'm not an R user and don't know anything about the *summary* command. It would be helpful if you were to generalize your question about the *summary* command vs *ANOVA* by removing the R references and describing more generally what it is you think they do.

Answer (score 2):

Probably I know what you mean, but at first, I present what I concluded from your question. You have single quantitive response (DV) variable Y and several independent variables (IV) / predictors, e.g. A, B.
I assume you're asking inter alia what's the difference between these two approaches:

- **anova(lm(Y ~ A * B, data=my_data))**

  From anova(stats)
- **summary(lm(Y ~ A * B, data = my_data))** or to get coefficients

  **printCoefmat(summary(lm(Y ~ A * B, data = my_data)))$coefs**

  From summary.lm(stats)

Probably you're trying to test the significance of additive effects of those IVs.

Below I'm using the R convention:

- Y ~ 1 - empty model only with the mean
- A:B - only interaction between A and B
- A * B - adds both of the IVs A and B as well as their interaction A:B

The **first** case (anova) is Test I type or sequential and you're comparing bigger and bigger models, starting from an empty model (with only mean).
In this case the order of IVs is important:

For Y ~ A * B you're goint to compare such models:

- Y ~ 1 versus Y ~ 1 + A
- Y ~ 1 + A versus Y ~ A + B
- Y ~ 1 + A + B versus Y ~ 1 + A + B + A:B

**Watch out** Here, the order is important: Y ~ A * B and Y ~ B * A will lead to different tests.

In the **second** case (summary) you're comparing the full model and almost full model without effect of particular IV. That is called Test III type or marginal. For Y ~ A * B are performed three tests comparing these pairs of models (the second in each pair is always full):

- Y ~ 1 + A + A:B versus Y ~ 1 + A + B + A:B
- Y ~ 1 + B + A:B versus Y ~ 1 + A + B + A:B
- Y ~ 1 + A + B versus Y ~ 1 + A + B + A:B

---

**The most important part**

If you're using Test III type / marginal with full model Y ~ A * B, that is
Y ~ A + B + A:B you would knock out only one factor at a time, so if you knock out A you leave the interaction A:B, so an influence from A isn't deleted completly.

**ANOVA is all about comparing two models. You can literally compare any two models in the following manner:**

`model1 = lm(Y ~ A * C, data = my_data)
model2 = lm(Y ~ A * B * C, data = my_data)
anova(model1, model2)`

**Here, I compared the model with all IVs with a model without B and its interactions with diffrent IVs (e.g. A:B or C:B), (but interaction A:C holds).
Probably, you cannot do that with summary.**

Comment: I get it what you're saying and you have understood what approaches I was talking about. Essentially what I'm interested in is where I can find information useful in the decision whether to delete or not a predictor. I start the analysis fitting a model with all the predictors, then through summary approach (looking at the p-value) I check which predictor is less significant for my model and possibly delete it. From here, what contribution might bring an anova test? May I compare the initial model (all predictors) with the second one (with some of them deleted)?

Comment: Using ANOVA you're able to test literally any two models like Y ~ A * C against Y ~ A * B * C, whereas with summary you delete only one compound. Summary applied to Y ~ A * B * C could delete B, but it leaves B's interactions, e.g A:B and B:C, thus influence fom B isn't deleted completly (look at the edited answer).